# modular exponentiation in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modular, exponentiation

I need to implement a modular exponentiation in vhdl for a spartan 6, with google i found the following paper describing a fast implementation for an virtex 4
https://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2007/47270272/47270272.pdf

I'm wondering if it could be used on a spartan 6, but i can't find the source code anywhere.
I also found this datasheet form helion technology http://www.heliontech.com/downloads/modexp_xilinx_datasheet.pdf but it seems to be much slower than the above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the paper, it does not appear that any Virtex-4 specific features are used, so whether the implementation can fit in a Spartan 6 depends on the required resources for  SLICE, BRAM, and DSP48.

The resource overview is shown in "Table 3. Performances of our modular exponentiator" of the paper, says SLICE: 3937, BRAM: 7, DSP48: 17, in Virtex-4 resources.

BRAMs in Virtex 4 and Spartan 6 are both 18 Kb, and DSP48 are both "18 x 18 multiplier, an adder, and an accumulator", so these resources are similar and it is reasonable to compare the requirements.

The SLICE structure is different in Virtex 4 and Spartan 6, so a compare of logic requirements may be done by going over the "Logic Cells" number, for an apples to apples compare.  The 3937 SLICEs in Virtex 4 may be about 8900 logic cells (2.25 logic cell/SLICE in Virtex 4), which then converts to 1384 SLICEs in Spartan 6 (6.4 logic cell/SLICE).

So to fit the design in Spartan 6, you may look for a device with SLICE: 1384, BRAM: 7, DSP48: 17.

Note that the above is a "back of the envelope" calculation, and subtle details or specific device fitting can give a result that differs, but the approach is useful to determine it it looks like a possible solution.